# Creating an anonymous class in the return statement

Tags: java, generics

I have the following static method:

```
public static <E> Tree<E> leaf(E leaf) {
    return new Tree<E>() {
        @Override
        public <R> R accept(TreeVisitor<E, R> visitor) {
            return visitor.visit(leaf); //1 Ok in Java 8, fail in Java < 8
        }
    };
}
```

While I was developing it in Java 8; it compiled fine, now when I have to move back to Java 7 the line `//1` causes a compile error:

> Cannot refer to the non-final local variable leaf defined in an
>   enclosing scope

*Why is it permitted in Java 8 to refer to non-final variables?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java 8 allows access to effective final variables (i.e. local variables that are not final but can be marked as final, since their value is not changed) from anonymous classes and lambda expressions.

You can overcome your compilation problem in older Java versions by making `leaf` final :

```
public static <E> Tree<E> leaf(final E leaf) {
    return new Tree<E>() {
        @Override
        public <R> R accept(TreeVisitor<E, R> visitor) {
            return visitor.visit(leaf); //1 Ok in Java 8, fail in Java < 8
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

yeah that's actually what you have to expect because starting from Java 8:

> a local class can access local variables and parameters of the enclosing block that are final or effectively final. A variable or parameter whose value is never changed after it is initialized is effectively final.

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html)

**Effectively final:** A variable or parameter whose value is never changed after it is initialized.